# Is there an ampersand (&) analogue to the pipe (|)?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In the Cypher query `match (a)-[:X|Y]-(b) return a, b` we match all the a, b pairs that are either X-related or Y-related. What if we want to find all the a, b pairs that are *both* X-related and Y-related?

Neither `match (a)-[:X&Y]-(b) return a, b` nor `match (a)-[:X&&Y]-(b) return a, b` seems to work. Is the only way to do it using a statement like this?

```
match (a)-[X]-(b)
where (a)-[Y]-(b)
return a, b
```

*EDIT*: For some reason I said the above statement included a `with` clause. I've removed that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any `with` statement?

There is no support for ampersand (&) operator in relationship types. You showed one way that this could be achieved with `WHERE` statement.

```
match (a)-[:X]-(b)
where (a)-[:Y]-(b)
return a, b
```

Another way is to use two `MATCH` statements

```
match (a)-[:X]-(b)
match (a)-[:Y]-(b)
return a, b
```

I am sure there are other ways as well

Comment: Ah right, thanks. And yeah, the `with` thing was just a brain fart on my side, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are returning a different (b) for [:X] and [:Y]. If so a query of this type may meet your need?

```
match (a:Person{RN:1})-[r:father|mother]->(b:Person) 
with a,collect(b.RN) as bc,collect(type(r)) as rels
with a,bc,rels 
return a.RN,bc,rels
```

You could unwind the b-collection if you want to get two rows.